# Can I get a working visa in Australia/New Zealand without a degree?

Tags: visa, working-visas, immigration, australia, new-zealand

I have Italian citizenship and I would like to go work in Australia or New Zealand for an undefinite amount of time.

I don't have a bachelor's degree, would it be enough for me to get a job offer as a programmer to then get a working visa?

Comment: How much experience do you have?

Comment: I started recently... 6 months.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way for you to get started living in Australia or New Zealand is probably to get a working holiday visa (assuming you're under 30).

- Australia: [Working Holiday visa (subclass 417)](https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/417-)
- New Zealand: [Italy Working Holiday Visa](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/apply-for-a-visa/about-visa/italy-working-holiday-visa)

There are restrictions, such as the maximum term with a single employer is 6 months (Australia) or 3 months (New Zealand). After you get some local work experience, you may be able to get a proper job offer, perhaps from one of the employers you worked for during your working holiday. Then, with a job offer, you can apply for a longer term working visa. If that all works out, then you may be able to turn that working visa into a permanent residence visa.

Comment: Would it be a viable possibility for me to apply online for jobs in Australia/New Zealand and mention in the interview that I (will) have the working holiday visa? Or do you know of any other way I could get a job offer there without leaving my current country?

Comment: @Cress: Yes, it's possible to do that. Note that many (or most) job listings will have a statement like "Must have the right to work in NZ", and some employers won't make the effort to interview if you don't yet. Also, most employers will require or at least prefer an in-person interview.